# How do you tell how fast an arctangent formula for pi is to compute?

Tags: trigonometry, computer-science, pi

I think I discovered a **very** (compared to other arctangent formulas) fast arctangent formula for pi.  My question is: Is it the best?  My formula starts:
$$\frac{\pi}{4} = 1065\arctan(\frac{1}{1356}) + \arctan(\frac{1}{13211959}) + \arctan(\frac{1}{1661269101985727}) \pm \dots$$
There are $15$ arctangents in total.  All of the arctangents except for the last one have a numerator of $1$.  The last one has a numerator that is $3316$ digits long but it has a denominator that is $68680$ digits long so the numerator doesn't matter too much.  All of the arctangents besides the first is either multiplied by $1$ or $-1$, whereas the first is multiplied by $1065$.

Because the denominators are all so big it makes it converge very fast.  By estimating it's score (an approximate multiple of time) using $\sum \frac{1}{\ln(b_n)}$ where $b_n$ is the $n$-th denominator, we get a score of **$\approx$0.1169**, which is **incredibly** low!  We would need to increase it a little though, to account for the fact that the last arctangent's numerator is not $1$.  Although I don't think we would need to increase it by much because that arctangent's denominator is SO large ($\approx 10^{68679}$), but do I?

On [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula#More_terms) it lists the most efficient currently know Machin-like formulas for pi and by applying the score formula we used earlier to them we get that the best one is $\approx 0.58232$.  Because a lower score (meaning smaller time) is better mine seems to be the best arctangent formula for pi there is.  Please tell me if I am correct or if I've made a mistake.

List of the terms in my formula:

1. $1065 * \arctan(1 / 1356)$
2. $\arctan(1 / 13211959)$
3. $\arctan(1 / 1661269101985727)$
4. $-1 * \arctan(1 / 45795729185495880262825011844107)$
5. $-1 * \arctan(1 / 2700517276808431966374537126272309157148546111625235650501520960)$
6. $\arctan(1 / \approx 10^{127})$
7. $\arctan(1 / \approx 10^{254})$
8. $-1 * \arctan(1 / \approx 10^{510})$
9. $\arctan(1 / \approx 10^{1020})$
10. $\arctan(1 / \approx 10^{2042})$
11. $-1 * \arctan(1 / \approx 10^{4084})$
12. $\arctan(1 / \approx 10^{8170})$
13. $\arctan(1 / \approx 10^{16340})$
14. $\arctan(1 / \approx 10^{32682})$
15. $-1 * \arctan(\approx 10^{3315} / \approx 10^{68679})$

If you have any questions just ask! :)

PS: If this is confirmed to be correct then I can explain my method of getting this formula and how to get infinitely many formulas like it.

Comment: Pity about that last term. Have you seen http://www.machination.eclipse.co.uk/ ?

Comment: @PM2Ring I could replace (15) with some other terms that all have numerators of 1, but it would take my computer very long to compute them.  I will check out the site.